# How do you assign the value of a parameter to a variable in UNIX?

Tags: shell, variables, parameters

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! $1 ]
then
 echo "no param"
else
    set FAV_COLOR=$1
    echo "My fav color is ${FAV_COLOR}"
fi
```

This is not working how I expected:

```
>favcol.sh blue
My fav color is FAV_COLOR=blue
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You've asked for bash and used `set` which is a csh syntax...

Comment: @dmckee should be exports then?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove `set`.

```
FAV_COLOR=$1
echo "My fav color is ${FAV_COLOR}"
```

Or if you want to set it so that it is available to subsequent programs run in the shell:

```
export FAV_COLOR=$1
echo "My fav color is ${FAV_COLOR}"
```

The `export` keyword is described fairly well [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-bash.html).

Comment: For values of "global" than mean affecting all the descendant processes of the current shell, anyway.